# Android not showing any JPEG images

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-imageview, android-image, android-gridview

Android Emulator shows blank screen, images still opens up (assuming that 150,150 pics are there). In another word, my 150,150 thumbs are behind the blank screen

My images are larger than 150*150, I followed the link below to load large bitmap efficiently, but it still doesnt work.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

These is my code in imageAdapter

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if(reqHeight + reqWidth == 0){

            return inSampleSize;
        }
        else if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
```

I have also added my full imageAdapter class for more information.

```
package com.example.first;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.util.Log;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.h18, R.drawable.h17, R.drawable.h16, R.drawable.h15, 



    };
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if(reqHeight + reqWidth == 0){

            return inSampleSize;
        }
        else if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageview;
        if(convertView == null){
            imageview = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150,150));
            imageview.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);



        }else{
            imageview = (ImageView) convertView;
        }



        imageview.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource( null, mThumbIds[position], 150, 150));
        return imageview;
    }

    private Resources getResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

Any help with this appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using PNG images, because I am not very sure if android supports JPEG

Comment: same problem with PNG, JPEG images are there and opens up.. BUT there is this blank screen on top..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your Bitmap-loader with `null` instead of your `Resources` object.

replacing

```
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource( null, mThumbIds[position], 150, 150)
```

With

```
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource( mContext.getResources(), mThumbIds[position], 150, 150)
```

Should do the trick.